# Remove file once served?

Tags: http, go

Is there a way to remove the whole static directory from the server once its content was served for one time? (with served I mean being displayed on the browser once).

```
func main() {
    fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(tempDir))
    http.Handle("/", fs)
    http.HandleFunc("/app/wo", workOrderApp)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+os.Args[1], nil))
}

func workOrderApp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    workOrderAppProcess(w)
    time.Sleep(time.Duration(4 * time.Second)) //some time to let render the html
    os.RemoveAll(tempDir)
}
```

The `sleep os.RemoveAll` was a hit and miss. Had to adjust the sleep time to a few seconds otherwise the file sometimes was served and sometimes not, I believe because bandwith or network related stuff. But it also had the side effect of delaying the whole rendering of the page.

In this example I remove all the directory, which is what I want.

```
func workOrderAppProcess(aid, date, language, token string, w http.ResponseWriter) {
    zipDir := os.Args[2]
    if _, err := os.Stat(tempDir); os.IsNotExist(err) {
        log.Printf("Creating directory: %v", tempDir)
        err := os.MkdirAll(tempDir, 0777)
        if err != nil {
            log.Print(err.Error())
        }
    }
    log.Printf("Extracting file: %v to: %v", date+".zip", tempDir)
    zipPath, _ := filepath.Abs(zipDir + "/" + date + ".zip")
    app.ExtractZip(zipPath, tempDir)
    batch := app.ReturnBatchNumber(tempDir + date)
    typesData := app.ReturnWorkTypeData(app.ParseXML(tempDir + date + "/" + batch + "_type_list.xml"))
    record := app.FindAppointmentRecord(aid, app.ParseXML(tempDir+date+"/"+batch+"_appt.xml"))
    signatureFileURL := app.ReturnSignatureFileURL(tempDir+date, aid, date)
    app.RenderTemplate(record, typesData, "template/wo.html", language, "/"+signatureFileURL, w)
}
```

Comment: Probably the `HandleFunc` only starts sending the response to the client _after_ the function returns, so if you remove the file in that function, the server can't send the file anymore. Why are you doing this anyway, why are you using temp files (can't you use memory?) and do they have to be removed immediately, or can a background task or process do the cleanup later?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is causing the HTTP handler to wait 4 seconds, delete the files, *then* finalize the HTTP response. Just remove the sleep.

```golang
func workOrderApp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    workOrderAppProcess(w)
    os.RemoveAll(tempDir)
}
```

This is more efficient, more directly reflects your intention, and doesen't leave the HTTP connection open needlessly for an extra 4 seconds.

If you have other logic in your handler not shown, and you want to ensure that the delete happens in all cases, a `defer` can be useful:

```golang
func workOrderApp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    workOrderAppProcess(w)
    defer os.RemoveAll(tempDir)
    /* Other logic that may do things */
}
```

After discussion in chat, it's apparent that `workOrderAppProcess` is rendering your HTML, and that `os.RemoveAll` is removing the images needed by that HTML. To solve this, you need to delay the removal, but *after* serving the HTML. This can be done with a simple goroutine:

```golang
func workOrderApp(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    workOrderAppProcess(w)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(60 * time.Second)
        os.RemoveAll(tempDir)
    }()
}
```

Comment: This was the concern expressed in the case. The sleep - remove is a hit or miss and also added unnecesary delay to the end user. Will try the defer and report back, that may work.

Comment: If removing the file in your handler causes problems, that means something important is happening that's not shown in your example. Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: with the sleep. And it's not working with the defer :(

Comment: The page is rendered with no images in it.

Comment: added relevant function in the original post

Comment: If the directory you're deleting contains those images, that makes sense. You're (presumably) serving the HTML file, then deleting the images. You should instead delete the images _as they are served_.

Comment: Can you explain your actual goal here? What is the reason for deleting these files once they are served? How many files are there, and what do they contain? Are they all images? A mixture of images and HTML? Anything else?

Comment: Will explaing the logic of the webapp as succinct as possible. User enters date, order, then the app looks into the archive for the file [date].zip, unzips it, then I look for some relevant data in the XML with the order number as index, and also the signature file (png). All this is then sent to the template engine for rendering the HTML and then to the http iowriter. Everything works dandy but when try to render the PNG. WITH the sleep, sometimes ir rendered, some times it does not. If i either set a long sleep (5+ seconds) or remove entirely the sleep-removeall sentences, it works 100% time

Comment: The reason it sometimes works with the sleep, and sometimes not, is that you're sleeping at entirely the wrong time. You're sleeping _before_ finalizing the HTTP response for the rendered HTML. This means that the browser may wait the full 4 seconds before finishing rendering.  If you do the sleep in a deferred function, you're probably safe--assuming that no single image takes more than 4 seconds to start serving (could be a problem on a slow network)

Comment: Regarding the "delete files as they are served" yes, may be the solution, but have no idea how to proceed. Any example?

Comment: The _correct_ logic is probably to just unconditionally delete everything 60 seconds (or some other duration long enough to guarantee everything is done fetching it), after it's created.

Comment: Well, you're already doing the "delete as they are served" logic, except that you're deleting everything when the HTML is served, rather than each individual file as each individual file is served. So you'd just need to adjust that.

Comment: Another option might be to just treat these files as a cache, and auto-reap them every hour or something. Then change your handler to look for the cache--if it's there, serve it, if not, unzip it.  Whether this makes sense depends on what behavior you ultimately want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226666/discussion-between-gabriel-a-zorrilla-and-flimzy).

Comment: Went with the third option. Thanks a lot for your time in chat!